# System of multivariable equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Show that the system $$\begin{cases}f(x,\,y)=x^{2}-y^{2}-1=0,\\g(x,\,y)=x^{4}+y^{5}-2=0.\end{cases}$$ has at least two real solutions.

What would be the best way of showing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x^2=y^2+1 \implies (y^2+1)^2+y^5-2=0$ for solutions. The LHS changes signs for $y=-1, 0, 1$ implying the existence of at least two real roots.